# C++ read registry string value in char*

Tags: c++, unicode, registry, char

I'm reading a registry value like this:

```
char mydata[2048];
DWORD dataLength = sizeof(mydata);
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

..... open key, etc
ReqQueryValueEx(hKey, keyName, 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)mydata, &dataLength);
```

My problem is, that after this, mydata content looks like: [63, 00, 3A, 00, 5C, 00...], i.e. this looks like a unicode?!?!.

I need to convert this somehow to be a normal char array, without these [00], as they fail a simple logging function I have. I.e. if I call like this: WriteMessage(mydata), it outputs only "c", which is the first char in the registry. I have calls to this logging function all over the place, so I'd better of not modify it, but somehow "fix" the registry value. Here is the log function:

```
void Logger::WriteMessage(const char *msg)
{
 time_t now = time(0);
 struct tm* tm = localtime(&now);
 std::ofstream logFile;

 logFile.open(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

 if ( logFile.is_open() )
 {
  logFile << tm->tm_mon << '/' << tm->tm_mday << '/' << tm->tm_year << ' ';
  logFile << tm->tm_hour << ':' << tm->tm_min << ':' << tm->tm_sec << "> ";
  logFile << msg << "\n";
  logFile.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx)().

Comment: The code I used: WideCharToMultiByte(CP_NONE, 0, (LPCWSTR)keyval, -1, ascii, asciil, NULL, NULL);

Comment: Unless you really need to build your project with the Character Set property set to Unicode (the default under VS2008), Maurizio's solution is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions here:

1. Change in your code to `wchar_t mydata[2048];`. As the underlying code is UNICODE you will get the best performance.
2. Use `RegQueryValueExA()` if performance in this area is not your concern.